# Is there a way to get the DESCryptoServiceProvider to not use special characters like plus signs?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, base64, url-encoding

When creating an encrypted string:

```
 using(var cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
      cryptoProvider.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);
      cryptoProvider.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);

      var encryptedString = cryptoProvider
        .CreateEncryptor()
        .TransformFinalBlock(serializedBytes, 0, serializedBytes.Length);

      return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedString);
```

Is there anyway to stop it from using certain characters?  The character that is actually causing problems is the "+" sign.  The problem is apparent when asp.net decodes and (for example) a + sign is turned into a space.

There might be other characters that would be fall into the same issue, but the + sign seems to be the only one I have encountered as an issue.  Is there a way to either not have the encryption use a certain character, or a way to protect against this in my encryption logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my particular case where the encrypted value is used in url's, to avoid the mentioned url encoding/decoding management nightmare, using

```
HttpUtilityServer.UrlTokenEncode / UrlTokenDecode
```

takes care of all the issues presented with the padded Ascii values used by the To64BaseString().

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could just call `Url.Encode()` on the resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely unrelated to encryption and DES.

It's Base64 that's responsible for producing those characters. Since there are only 62 alphanumeric ASCII characters, it needs two more characters to get the full 64. By convention those two are `+` and `/` and for padding it uses `=`.

Now you can substitute some other characters for `+` and `/` with `string.Replace` if you want, or you can use url encoding on the output.

Comment: I have already went the route of Url.Encode for the output which has been more of a management headache that has lead me back to root.  If I wanted to do a replace on +, what is a character I could use to substitute on the generated output that I would need to re-replace that wouldn't automatically cause the same url decoding issues?